# Hover and click is not working in IE11 from Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am not able to hover and click on submenu in IE 11 using selenium. I am using below code.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator))).click().build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Locator)]")));  
// until this submenu is found
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Sub Menu Locator))).build().perform();;
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Sub Menu Locator)).click();
```

Can any one please share the workaround.

Comment: Can you please share what error you are getting ? and HTMl code

Answer (score 0):

When *Mouse Hover* over an *element* unveils the sub-element you don't have to click. You can use the following code block to *Mouse Hover* a *element* and click on *sub-element* :

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator))).perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Sub Menu Locator)).click();
```

Comment: Thank for the code but somehow this is not working in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

if you get an elementnotvisible exception.you can try the code

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator))).perform();
//SubMenu locaotor
WebElement SubMenu = driver.findelements(By.Xpath(SubLocator));
String onClickScript = 'if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent(\'MouseEvents\');evObj.initEvent(\'click\',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject){ arguments[0].fireEvent(\'onclick\');}'
js.executeScript(onClickScript, SubMenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, Selenium's Webdriver has some flakiness with IE11 and the web driver detailed in this [issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403) here. A fix I have used is to send Keyboard commands instead of .click.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator))).build().perform();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Locator)]")));  
// until this submenu is found
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Sub Menu Locator))).build().perform();;
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Sub Menu Locator)).SendKeys(Keys.Space);
```

I think it is better to use the spacebar key because if are you working with a form it will send the form if you use ENTER. I have also had some luck with Javascript Executors, but I recommend you start with keyboard commands first.